# Is it possible to make the Zrinity XMS generate the return-path in the emails it sends?

Tags: email

We're using the XMS mail server from Zrinity. We're using verp-variables in our mails to be able to handle bounces correctly. We're a bit confused for how to get the return-path correct in our mails.

Can the XMS generate the return-path using the verp-variables or do we have to construct the return-path string ourselves? If it can, how do we instruct it to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return-path is generated, first from the value used by your smtp client at the mail from: command, but also can encode values with the use of [AttributeMapFilter](http://www.zrinity.com/xms/docs/xms.filter.data.attributemapfilter.html) and [VerpBounceFilter](http://www.zrinity.com/xms/docs/xms.filter.bounce.verpbouncefilter.html).

AttributeMapFilter (inside SMTPService)

```
        <filter
            class="xms.filter.data.AttributeMapFilter"
            attributemap="verpmap"
            remove="false" />
```

The map would have entries, such as

camid=X-camid

VerpBounceFilter (inside SMTPService)

```
        <filter
            class="xms.filter.bounce.VerpBounceFilter"
            feedbackaddresslist="Feedback Addresses"
            verpprefix="verpprefix"
            verpvariables="env_recipient,camid"
            action="accept"
            domainlist="Local Domains">
            <action
                class="xms.action.DBAction"
                datasource="mydatasource"
                event="*">
                <sql>
                    <![CDATA[
                        INSERT INTO bounce (recipientaddress, env_from, bounceaddress, message, bouncetype, camid)                                    
                        VALUES(?,?,?,?,${bounce_type},${verp_camid?default(-1)});
                    ]]>
                </sql>
                <param>${verp_env_recipient?default('')}</param>
                <param>${env_from?default('')}</param>
                <param>${env_recipient}</param>
                <param>${bounce_message}</param>
            </action>
        </filter>
```

If you generate messages with TemplateSerice, add an instance of VerpBounceFilter to the job, without an action.

In that configuration, camid would be supplied by one of the providers in the job.

Comment: Nice to see you here Greg :)

Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work properly yet. It is the filter in the TemplateService I'm interested in.

When I added "env_recipient" as a verp-variable the return-path is generated and starts to look something I'd like.
<filter class="xms.filter.bounce.VerpBounceFilter" domainlist="Local Domains" feedbackaddresslist="Feedback Addresses" verpprefix="verpprefix" action="drop" verpvariables="env_recipient, cid, mid, sid" />

The cid, mid and sid exists in the verp-map and evaluates correct as x-headers but evaluates to "=" in the return-path. Why?

Comment: Spaces are not allowed between the verpvariables in the VerpBounceFilter.

verpvariables="env_recipient,cid,mid,sid"